# jQuery scroll offset

Tags: jquery

Using this jQuery: https://github.com/JamyGolden/PlusAnchor

I am looking to make it scroll to the specific anchor but give it an top offset of 50px. I have a fixed header of 50px and when the page scrolls, the header covers part of the section.

Any help or a point in the right direction is appreciated.

Thanks

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').plusAnchor({
easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
speed: 800,
onInit: function( base ) {
if ( base.initHash != '' && $(base.initHash).length > 0 ) {

window.location.hash = 'hash_' + base.initHash.substring(1);

window.scrollTo(0, 0);

$(window).load( function() {

 timer = setTimeout(function() {

$(base.scrollEl).animate({
scrollTop: $( base.initHash ).offset().top

}, base.options.speed, base.options.easing);
}, 500); // setTimeout

}); // window.load
}; // if window.location.hash

} // onInit
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: can't you use the better jquery scrollTo plugin? http://flesler.blogspot.it/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: I could but this works fine for me and it's smaller. The developer responded to my github issue and it's been resolved. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found here: https://github.com/JamyGolden/PlusAnchor/issues/1